# Why is the first character of the first line of a file in windows a 0?

Tags: java, windows, utf-8, nio

So I'm reading a plain text file in Java, and I'd like do identify which lines start with "abc". I did the following:

```
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toAbsolutePath(), charset);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if (line.startsWith("abc")) {
       // Do something
   }
}
```

But if the first line of the file is "abcd", it won't match. By debugging I've found out that the first character is a 0 (non-printable character), and because of this it won't match. Why is that so? How could I robustly identify which lines start with "abc"?

EDIT: perhaps I should point out that I'm creating the file using notepad

Comment: After reading line you can trim non printable characters.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman trim() removes only whitespace characters, it doesn't do anything to non-printable characters

Comment: I am not talking about String.trim(), I was talking about writing your custom trim! :P

Comment: Is the charset (StandardCharsets.UTF_8) you are using the right one? Make sure you save the file using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman right, but I'd like to understand why is this character there.

Comment: @BheshGurung I'm selecting UTF_8 on notepad

Comment: Are you sure it is _actually_ 0? Try and print the value of this string's `.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a few problems with UTF-8, and as such it is a heavy user of the [UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

If my guess is correct, the first three bytes would then be (in hexadecimal): 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf.

Given that, for instance, Excel creates UTF-8 CSV files with a BOM prefix, I wouldn't be surprised at all if Notepad did as well...

edit: not surprisingly, it seems this is the case: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432584/how-to-make-notepad-to-save-text-in-utf-8-without-bom).

Comment: Correct! It was a question mark (and not 0 as I've stated). Thanks a lot!

Comment: But he is reading using a UTF-8 Reader, so the BOM would be a single `char` with value 0xFEFF.  If it was then output to (for example) a LATIN-1 console, he would see a `?`.

Comment: @StephenC uh, yeah, I meant the first three bytes, sorry... Fixed

Comment: @Thiago if you have to process a lot of files issued from Windows, you may also encounter UTF-16... PowerShell writes files with this encoding by default!

Comment: @StephenC note though that this is a _UTF-8_ BOM, note UTF-16 or UTF-32

Comment: @fge - Yes.  And the UTF-8 BOM mark translates to 0xFEFF when you feed it through a UTF-8 to Unicode (or UTF-16) translator... like I said.