# How can I get ride of the white space at the top of my website?

Tags: django, html, parallax

Good day, I'm not really sure how to deal with this issue, but I'm really struggling to get rid of the white space at the top of my website. it's a single page with sections and parallax effect. 
When I launch it, I see the white space at the top, and when I start scrolling and reach the second section of the page then the white space disappears.
I have set the:
    body, html:{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

I have attached the website pictures as well.

And I'm using django, and not sure if the fact of putting my sections in different html files is causing this.
[image: First section which starts the website and parallax] [image: Second section which scrolls up and make white space disappear] [image: first section html code] [image] [image] [image] [image]
I'm not really sure of what to do now.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: In the future, it'd _really_ help to post your actual code, not screenshots -- thanks!

Comment: Sure thanks for the notice will try that

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was: 
just had to do this:

```
   background-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

and not have it cover the whole section

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this issue when I used Visual Studio to edit some django template files.  I ended up having to save the file without BOM.

[How to make Notepad to save text in UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432584/how-to-make-notepad-to-save-text-in-utf-8-without-bom)

[UTF-8 without BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: @chris_hawkes do you mind being a bite more specific on what you're trying to say?