# How can I use C++ to eliminate the BOM in a notepad .txt file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, io, byte-order-mark

I want to read in a .txt file using ifstream fin from library fstream, but there is a BOM at the beginning of the file that is causing problems.  Is there a way I can, from inside my C++ program, eliminate the BOM in the .txt file, so that fin can read it without any issues?  I know I can manually delete the BOM in the file myself, but I have multiple files I'm working with so this will take a while.

My question is similar to this one here, except this one deals in Java:

[How to make Notepad to save text in UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432584/how-to-make-notepad-to-save-text-in-utf-8-without-bom)

The answer from korifey is what I am looking for, where they said:

Use PushbackInputStream(in, 3)

Is there something similar I can do in C++ ?  It should also be noted that I only have Notepad (not Notepad++), and it is preferable to solve my problem without downloading any new software.  I also don't want to change how Notepad itself views BOMs, I just want to physically delete the BOM from my .txt file.  The BOM I'm dealing with is the first 8 characters.

Comment: [std::istream::ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)?

Comment: @Galik I'm not familiar with that command, what would it do?

Comment: Its a link, if you click on it, it takes you to the manual

Comment: I see, it'll ignore the first line when encountering an error.  Thanks, that should work.

Comment: If you show the code you are using to read in the file it would be easier for someone to give you a specific answer.

Comment: If you are reading `UTF-8` it is likely to be something like `file.ignore(3);` (`BOM` is three bytes).

Comment: I used fin.ignore(256, ' ');  because I wanted to start reading when reaching a space character, which would be after the BOM.  For some reason the BOM I had was 7 or 8 characters, and not 3 like I've been seeing many people say.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance, Then it's not a UTF-8 BOM. That's `EF BB BF`, which is three bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easiest by opening the file in binary mode, reading all the data and copying everything but the BOM to a different file, then removing the old file and finally renaming the new file back to the name of the old.

Comment: I'll probably use the fin.ignore() function like Galik mentioned, just because it seems a bit quicker.  Out of curiosity though, how would I read the file in binary mode, and then copy everything but the BOM to a different file?  The only way I could think of to store the data is in an int, but that's base 10.