# C++ - Am I using fin.ignore() incorrectly?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, ifstream, byte-order-mark

I have a .txt file called "1.txt" that I want to read in.  Since the file starts with 8 BOM characters, if I do the following:

```
ifstream fin("1.txt");

string temp = "";

char c = fin.get();

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        if (c >= ' ' && c <= 'z')
        {
            temp += c;
        }

        c = fin.get();
    }

    cout << temp;
```

This will print nothing, because of something the BOM is doing.

So, I decided to use the fin.ignore() function, in order to ignore the beginning BOM characters of the file.  However, still nothing is being printed.  Here is my complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream fin("1.txt");

if (fin.fail())
{
    cout << "Fail\n";
}

else
{
    string temp = ""; // Will hold 1.txt's contents.

    fin.ignore(10, ' ');
    // Ignore first 10 chars of the file or stop at the first space char,
    // since the BOM at the beginning is causing problems for fin to read the file.
    // BOM is 8 chars, I wrote 10 to just be safe.

    char c = fin.get();

    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        if (c >= ' ' && c <= 'z') // checks if c stores a standard char.
        {
            temp += c;
        }

        c = fin.get();
    }

    cout << temp;

    // PROBLEM:  No text is printed to the screen from the above command.

    cout << temp.size(); // prints 0
}
}
```

I hypothesize that after the:  ifstream fin("1.txt");  line, it is already too late, since the BOM probably affected things with fin then.  So I need to somehow tell fin to ignore the BOM characters before it reads in the file, but I can't use fin.ignore() since I wouldn't have declared a fin object yet.

Also, I know I can manually delete the BOM from my .txt file, but I'm looking for a solution that only involves me writing a C++ program.  If I have thousands or millions of .txt files, deleting manually is not an option.  Also, I'm not looking to download new software, like Notepad++

Here is all I have in the file  "1.txt":

> ÐÏà¡±á   Hello!

This site's formatting doesn't let me show it, but in the actual file there are about 15 spaces between the BOM and Hello!

Comment: At least I finally figured out what that is. It's the start of a .doc file (which has nothing to do with BOMs).

Comment: @chris Do you know of any way I can get rid of it in C++?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the previous suggestion of `.ignore`, but you'd better be sure it suffices to look only 10 bytes in. In an empty .doc file I created with Word 2016, it's 4106 bytes before the first space and there's still other stuff after it. `std::ifstream` doesn't guess at encodings or anything. I'd suggest exploring what happens line-by-line with a debugger to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @chris Sorry, which previous suggestion of .ignore are you referencing?

Comment: The one from the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047404/how-can-i-use-c-to-eliminate-the-bom-in-a-notepad-txt-file).

Comment: @Chris I tried Galik's suggestion in my code above though, but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: It looks like you are reading a *.doc binary file in text mode, and for some reason you think there is BOM in there. Open the file in binary mode `ifstream fin("1.txt", ios::binary);` and print the bytes `char buf[1]; while(fin.read(buf, 1)) cout << (int)buf[0] << " ";` to examine the values.

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but change `if (c >= ' ' && c <= 'z')` to `if (!std::iscntrl(c))` or, if you only want printable characters, `if (std::isprint(c))`. **That** "will check if c stores a standard character". As written it assumes a particular character encoding, and will give incorrect results if that assumption is wrong.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani If I read the file in in binary format, could I then just skip the first 10 bytes of so?  Would that ignore the first part of the .txt file?

Comment: @ Pete Becker I tried both of your suggestions, but I'm still getting nothing printed to the screen.

Comment: My answer to this question was found by dumb luck, to be quite honest. I already recommended using a debugger to figure out what exactly is happening. It turns out that a debugger would trivialize the process of finding the problem here. You'd immediately notice that `.eof()` returns true after the `ignore` call, prompting you to take out the `ignore` call and read byte by byte to see which one causes it, quickly seeing that the \x1a byte is the cause. This leads to a much more specific question of why \x1a is causing EOF or a much easier google search.

Comment: You can use `ifstream::seekg` to go to a specific location in the file. But it won't help much if you have a *.doc binary file. The conversion of DOC format to text is not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes), the character with value \x1a terminates input on Windows in text mode. You presumably have such a character right near the beginning. My empty .doc file has one as the 7th byte.

You should read the file in binary mode:

```
std::ifstream fin("1.txt", std::ios::binary);
```

You can still use `ignore` to ignore a prefix. However, it's kind of flaky ignoring until a specific character. The binary prefix could contain that character. If these prefixes are always the same length, ignoring a specific number of bytes suffices. In addition, you can't rely on looking at the file in Notepad to count the number of bytes. There are quite a few invisible characters. You should be looking at the hex view of the file instead. Many good text editors can do this, or you can use Powershell's `Format-Hex -Path <path>` command. For example, here's the first few lines of mine:

```
00000000   D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ÐÏ.à¡±.á........
00000010   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3E 00 03 00 FE FF 09 00  ........>...þ...
00000020   06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
```

It's unclear what the best way to remove the prefixes is without more information.

Comment: I used ios::binary to read in the file and it worked perfectly.  Now I have a big string with a bunch of Word text at the beginnings and ends of each file's contents, but trimming them shouldn't be a problem.  There are a few signs I can use; for example, if a program finds there aren't 10 printable characters in a row, that area is almost definitely in a Word prefix or suffix.  I could then delete all the characters until reaching a big break of space chars, since they separate the prefix, main text, and suffix of each file's contents.