# How do I create a download link for QR code?

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm using the QR google api to create QR codes but would like the ability to download the image in PHP.  I've looked online but can't seem to find anything helpful.  Any suggestions?

I'm creating the QR code like so:

```
function generateQR($url, $width = 150, $height = 150) {
    $url    = urlencode($url);
    $image  = '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs='.$width.'x'.$height.'&cht=qr&chl='.$url.'" alt="QR code" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/>';
    return $image;
}

echo(generateQR('http://google.com'));
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900207/return-a-php-page-as-an-image

Comment: Not sure what do you mean with "download the image in PHP". Surely you have to encode the url with urlencode, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a any binary safe function to retrieve and output the image with the right headers.

Remeber that allow_fopen_url must be On in PHP configuration.

Something like:

```
function forceDownloadQR($url, $width = 150, $height = 150) {
    $url    = urlencode($url);
    $image  = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs='.$width.'x'.$height.'&cht=qr&chl='.$url;
    $file = file_get_contents($image);
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.png");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-length: " . strlen($file)); // tells file size
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    echo $file;
    die;
}

forceDownloadQR('http://google.com');
```

Comment: of course, this needs to be sent prior to any other output, or output buffering must be on

Answer (score 1):

if you want to download the file onto your webserver(and save it), just use [copy()](http://www.php.net/copy)

```
copy($url, 'myfile.png');
```

This will not prompt a visitors web browser to save the file.