# text to char and char to image

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, casting

this is data inside the column:
column image
data  = ÿØÿác¡Exif

```
description = text
```

can i convert this to a character type then convert the character into a image file?

Comment: The `image` data type is binary.

Comment: so it means sql 2008 can simply convert it with out any commands? i need to have it converted for grabbing i.e saving image in another dbase

Comment: Where did you get the idea that SQL Server 2008 does implicit data conversion between CHAR and binary data types?!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx look for the table description please let me know if I was mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're wanting to do... Return the 'image' column as an image to the browser?  Or display an image with a description on a webpage?

If you want to return the image data as an image, for example in PHP you could do it like this: [Return a PHP page as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900207/return-a-php-page-as-an-image)