# Loading an image using a PHP script

Tags: php

I have an HTML page that has the content shown below.

I want to display the image in the browser using a PHP script file titled `"load_image.php"` that loads the image using the PHP script and passing the image to the html page for display in the browser.

What will be the best PHP sctipt to do that? The image, `image.gif`, is located in the same directory as the html page and the PHP script.

I included a PHP working script that I am currently using, however it has some limitations that I want to avoid with a different script.

There is a reason why I use a PHP script and not a simple link in the HTML page to load the image.

Thanks,
Menachem Blasberg

### HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="http://www.inoxel.com/load_image.php" >

</body>

</html>
```

The image is `my_image.gif`

### Current `"load_image.php"` PHP script:

```
<?php 

$my_image = "http://www.example.com/my_image.gif"; // Set image Full Path

readfile($my_image);

?>
```

Comment: What are the *limitations you want to avoid*?

Comment: That is what are you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900207/return-a-php-page-as-an-image

Answer (score 1):

```
/* load_image.php */
<?php 

$my_image = "http://www.example.com/my_image.gif"; 

?>
/* Your HTML FILE */
<?php include ('load_image.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="<?php echo $my_image ?>" >

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$path = 'http://www.inoxel.com/';
$image = 'load_image.php';
```

in Image

```
<img src="<?php echo $path.$image ?>" >
```

Comment: Did you check the answer??

Answer (score 0):

***Modify your code to***

```
<body>
<?php 
   echo "<img src='$my_image' >";
?>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. Note that I call the php file from my HTML page. It does work with my current implementation however I want to try a different method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = "https://example.com/March.jpg";
$contents =  file_get_contents($file);
$expires = 14 * 60*60*24;
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="March.jpg"'); //Use for force to download
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));
header("Cache-Control: public", true);
header("Pragma: public", true);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT', true);
echo $contents; //Image load
?>
```