# Php mysql arrange html output three by three

Tags: php, html, mysql

It may be looking pretty simple but it gives me headaches right now.

```
<?php

$sql = DB::query("SELECT `post_id` FROM `table` LIMIT 0,9");
foreach ($sql as $row){ 
$id = $row["post_id"];
}
```

And this is the output that i want to achieve:

```
<div class="row">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</div>
<div class="row">
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</div>
<div class="row">
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
</div>
```

Basically, every 3 elements to be encapsulated in their own div.

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an algorithm similar to this. It will add an open `<div>` at `1` and close `<div>` at `3`. You would have to accommodate for numbers that leave a remainder:

```
// Set the start at 1
$i = 1;
foreach ($sql as $row){
    // If the loop hits 1, add <div>
    if($i == 1)
        echo '<div>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo $id = "\t<li>".$row["post_id"].'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
    // If the loop hits 3, add </div>
    if($i == 3) {
        echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
        // Reset the counter
        $i = 0;
    }
    // Increment up
    $i++;
}
```

With random numbers will give you something like:

```
<div>
        <li>309781723</li>
        <li>1591425966</li>
        <li>1922824365</li>
</div>
<div>
        <li>1861766038</li>
        <li>2065624155</li>
        <li>504061231</li>
</div>
<div>
        <li>143488299</li>
        <li>806735480</li>
        <li>605627018</li>
</div>
<div>
        <li>1305718337</li>
        <li>2080669131</li>
        <li>314748482</li>
</div>
```

Here is another example: [Displaying data from arrays in a dynamic table PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202569/)

You can also do an `array_chunk()` similar to this. You don't need any calculations to accommodate for remainders in this scenario:

```
// Split into sets of 3
$arr    =   array_chunk($sql,3);
$a = 0;
// You could probably do an array_map() but I am not experienced enough
// with array_map() to do it efficiently...or even at all, to be perfectly honest
foreach($arr as $row) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++)
            $new[$a][]  =   $row[$i]['post_id'];
        // Assemble the rows via implode
        $nRow[] =   "\t<li>".implode("</li>".PHP_EOL."\t<li>",$new[$a])."</li>".PHP_EOL;

        $a++;
    }
// Implode with <div> wrappers
echo "<div>".PHP_EOL.implode("</div>".PHP_EOL."<div>".PHP_EOL,$nRow)."</div>";
```